# Python2.7: How to split a column into multiple column based on special strings like this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, split, multiple-columns

I'm a newbie for programming and python, so I would appreciate your advice!

I have a dataframe like this.
[image]
In 'info' column, there are 7 different categories: activities, locations, groups, skills, sights, types and other. and each categories have unique values within **[ ]**.(ie,"activities":**["Tour"]**)
I would like to split 'info' column into 7 different columns based on each category as shown below.

[image]

I would like to allocate appropriate column names and also put corresponding unique strings within [ ] to each row.

Is there any easy way to split dataframe like that?
I was thinking to use str.split functions to split into pieces and merge everthing later. But not sure that is the best way to go and I wanted to see if there is more sophisticated way to make a dataframe like this.

Any advice is appreciated!

--**UPDATE**--

When print(dframe['info']), it shows like this.
[image]

Comment: Please don't use images to share data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the content of the `info` column is JSON-formatted, so you can parse that into a dict object easily:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '''{"activities": ["Tour"], "locations": ["Tokyo"], "groups": []}'''
>>> j = json.loads(s)
>>> j
{u'activities': [u'Tour'], u'locations': [u'Tokyo'], u'groups': []}
```

Once you have the data as a dict, you can do whatever you like with it.

Comment: Hi @bgporter ! Thank you so much for the advice! As for the suggested equation; s = '''{"activities":["Tour"],~} , do you think if I can make equation with dataframe with specific column? Since Json format is in info column in the pandas dataframe, I wanted to do something like s = dframe['info'] 
to extract all row in info column but it did not work...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how to do it :

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

#Initial Dataframe is df
mylist = list(df['info'])
mynewlist = []

for l in mylist:
    mynewlist.append(ast.literal_eval(l))

df_info = pd.DataFrame(mynewlist)

#Add columns of decoded info to the initial dataset
df_new = pd.concat([df,df_info],axis=1)

#Remove the column info
del df_new['info']
```

Comment: Actually you dont need json since you already have a dictionary, sorry for overlooking. I have edited the code, please check if you get the right answer

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I run the code and I got an error.. It says "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'int'>". I am not sure what is causing this error, but I think for loop is causing the problem.. There is an arrow pointing for loop in error output. Do you have any idea how to solve the problem? @Gaurav Dhama

Comment: Hi! Thanks for providing the revised version! I tried it and still get the error, which says "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'int'>"... I would appreciate if you could provide any insight on this:)

Comment: Can you post the output of print(df['info'])

Comment: I could not figure out how to attach image here,  but print['info'] shows like this.
0        {"activities":["174::Sailing"],"locations":[],...
1        {"activities":["239::Archaeological Exploratio...
2        {"activities":["239::Mayan Ruin"],"locations":...
3        {"activities":["190::Wildlife Safari"],"locati...
4        {"activities":[],"locations":[],"groups":[],"s...
5        {"activities":[],"locations":[],"groups":[],"s...

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot:)

Comment: I have changed the code, the info column has strings basically which i did not realize earlier. Please try the code and let me know what happens

Answer (score -1):

You can use the json library to do that.

1) import the json libray

```
import json
```

2) Turn into string all the rows of that column and then Apply the json.loads function to all of them. Insert the result in an object

```
jsonO = df['info'].map(str).apply(json.loads)
```

3)The Json object is now a json dataframe in which you can navigate. For each columns of your Json dataframe, create a column in your final dataframe

```
df['Activities'] = jsonO.apply(lambda x: x['Activities'])
```

Here for one column of your json dataframe  each 'rows' is dump in the new column of your final dataframe df

4) Re-do 3 for all the columns you're interested in