# Having troubles cleaning data from JSON into Python

Tags: python, json, split

I have only just started learning python recently and I have no experience with JSON files.

When I import my JSON file it seems like an entire dictionary of items is in one column? I have been trying to split it but it doesn't seem to work.
[Here's a screenshot of how the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeZmp.png),  [but this is how the original data looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sREPW.png)

I tried `np.split` but there's a `TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [,] of 'class 'str'`

I also tried

`MRT = pd.read_json('mrt_stations.json')
MRT_Stations = MRT['Possible Locations'].map(str).apply(json.loads)
MRT_Stations['Address'] = jsonO.apply(lambda x: x['Address'])`

as I saw this on [Python2.7: How to split a column into multiple column based on special strings like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752135/python2-7-how-to-split-a-column-into-multiple-column-based-on-special-strings-l)

However, it returns a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

Would appreciate some help and thanks in advance!

Comment: you could try `json.load('mrt_stations.json')`

Comment: Nice question. Thank you for providing examples of your input data!

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat Hi I tried this but I got an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Possible Locations` column contains python `dict` objects. Not json strings. You're getting the `JSONDecodeError` with the execution of `MRT['Possible Locations'].map(str).apply(json.loads)` because you're trying to json decode a dict string, hence you receive the error about single vs. double quotes (JSON uses double quotes, python `dict` objects represent strings as either `'` or `"`)

Given the above, you should be able to parse the `Possible Locations` column via

```py
MRT_Stations = MRT['Possible Locations']
MRT_Stations['Address'] = MRT_Stations.apply(lambda x: x['Address'])
```

Comment: I tried the above code but there's a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str instead. I have encountered this same error when I attempted many different ways (sorry I can't exactly remember what I attempted besides the above 2)

Comment: Ah, indeed. It's because the `Possible Locations` column contains `dict` objects wrapped in a `list`. If each list in `Possible Locations` only contains 1 `dict`, then you should be able to get it working with `MRT_Stations['Address'] = MRT_Stations.apply(lambda x: x[0]['Address'])`. Is there more than 1 element in each list under `Possible Locations` that you need to process?

Comment: Yup there's more than 1 element. I was initially trying to split them all at once but i decided to try on 1 element('Address') first. There are 'Address','Blk No.','Building','Latitude','Longitude','Longitude','Postal Code','Road Name','Search Value','X','Y' in the file. I think hyperlink was a bit unclear I attached a screenshot above after the comma. I hope it gives you a clearer picture!

Comment: Could you copy-paste the content of a single cell from the `Possible Locations` columns? ie. `MRT.at[0, 'Possible Locations']`

Comment: I also tried the new code you suggested and the code could run but I'm entirely how to move forward with the output. I checked the `.dtypes` and it says `dtype('O')`

Can I ask further check if it is possible to do multiple columns at once? It would also be a great help if you could explain the code used. Thanks!

Comment: The output of `MRT.at[0, 'Possible Locations']` is `[{'ADDRESS': '10 JURONG EAST STREET 12 JURONG EAST MRT STATION SINGAPORE 609690',
  'BLK_NO': '10',
  'BUILDING': 'JURONG EAST MRT STATION',
  'LATITUDE': '1.33315261987297',
  'LONGITUDE': '103.742286544006',
  'LONGTITUDE': '103.742286544006',
  'POSTAL': '609690',
  'ROAD_NAME': 'JURONG EAST STREET 12',
  'SEARCHVAL': 'JURONG EAST MRT STATION',
  'X': '17869.0806001499',
  'Y': '35038.9471976683'}]`

Comment: The JSON file I referenced is from here: [https://github.com/xkjyeah/singapore-postal-codes/blob/master/mrt_stations.json]

Comment: So, it looks like the lists under `Possible Locations` only contains a single element. In the above case, that single element is `{'ADDRESS': '10 JURONG EAST STREET 12 JURONG EAST MR ... 99', 'Y': '35038.9471976683'}`. Thus, this code should work to extract the `ADDRESS` field from the `Possible Locations` dict: `MRT_Stations['Address'] = MRT_Stations.apply(lambda x: x[0]['Address'])`. To do the same for `Building`: `MRT_Stations['Building'] = MRT_Stations.apply(lambda x: x[0]['BUILDING'])`.  ALSO, `dtype('O')` is the `object` dtype. A dict is an `object`. unlike primitives like `str` or `int`

Comment: I tried the code on `Building` but I got `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Did it work for `Address`? If so, then I cannot explain why it would work for `Address` and not `Building`, as they're both just keys to the underlying `dict`

Answer (score 0):

Does this throw an error when reading the file?

```
import json
import pd

with open('mrt_stations.json') as json_file:
  mrt_json = json.load(json_file)

mrt_df = pd.DataFrame(data=mrt_json)
print(mrt_df)

mrt_stations = mrt_df['Possible Locations']
mrt_stations['Address'] = mrt_stations.apply(lambda x: x['Address'])
```

Comment: This throws a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` on the line `mrt_stations = mrt_df['Possible Locations']`

Comment: try with the updated code . sorry i had forgot to add DF creation line